# why if (built-in object)Object executed as a function with parameter, it outputs array named 'String'?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, prototype

```js
let test=new Object('test')
console.log(test) // String{'test'} which is array. 

// if I log like below
console.log(test[0]) //'t'
console.log(test[1]) //'e'
console.log(test[2]) //'s'
console.log(test[3]) //'t'
```

I looked for property of Object but I couldn't find anything to explain this.. help!@

Comment: What did you expect that `'test'` parameter to do?

Comment: [MDN documentation link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Object)

Answer (score 1):

The `Object()` constructor sees the string you pass, and returns the equivalent of `new String('test')`. It does that for all the primitive types. If you pass an object, you get back that object. If you pass nothing, you get back a new empty Object instance, essentially the same as `let test = {};`.

And it's not an array, it's a String instance.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer, the primitive types are converted to corresponding primitive object instances. You can always get which instance class is an object of:

```js
let test = new Object('test')

console.log('Instance of:', test.__proto__.constructor.name);
```